# Put a Radio Button over a div when there is no space anymore

Tags: css, html

I want these radioboxes hover over the divs topchoice and bottomchoice.
I will change the width of the divs "choicefirstleft" and "choicesecondleft" and it could happen that the width would actually get 100%.
As you can see in the example on jsfiddle as soon as the width gets close to 100% the radiobutton gets moved down...

How can i achieve that these buttons are over the colored divs?
I don't have a clue.

HTML:

```
<div id="results">
    <div id="topchoice">
        <div class="result">
            <?php echo $topresult; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="choicefirstleft">
            <label for="yes">Ja</label>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" id="yes" value="1" name="votingvalue"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomchoice">
        <div class="result">
            <?php echo $bottomresult; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="choicesecondleft">
            <label for="no">Nein</label>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" id="no" value="2" name="votingvalue"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #topchoice{
        margin-top: 40px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    #bottomchoice{
        margin-top: 5px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    #choicefirstleft{
        width:30%;
        background-color:greenyellow;
        float:left;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #choicesecondleft{
        width:99%;
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #results{
         font-size: x-large;
        width: 50%;
        margin:0 auto;   
        color: white;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #results input{
        float:right;


        z-index: 4;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3Qgf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the container

```
position: relative;
```

and then

```
position: absolute;
```

on the radio buttons (with a new class)

http://jsfiddle.net/K3Qgf/1/